# Como sacar las variables que me interesan de un JSOn en python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Tengo un JSON con ciertos campos:

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
  }
```

Y no soy capaz de sacar individualmente los campos de dentro del address. He conseguido almacenar en variables el nombre, usuario, etc.

```
recibido = requests.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
text = recibido.text
data = json.loads(text)

# Acceder a los datos JSON
user = data[0]
nombre = user['nombre']
print(nombre)
address = user['address, zipcode']
print(address)
```

Alguien sabe como podría sacar el código postal?

Comment: No necesitas ninguna sintaxis especial o "nueva" para eso. Simplemente se aplica la lógica. Si `d` es un diccionario `d["clave"]` es lo que este ahí guardado. Si lo que hay ahí guardado es otro diccionario, entonces `d["clave"]` es a su vez un diccionario y le puedes aplicar de nuevo `["otra_clave"]`, es decir `d["clave"]["otra_clave"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con lo siguiente:

```py
cp = user['address']['zipcode']
print(cp)
```

Mediante los primeros corchetes (`[]`) te metes en la parte de `address` y luego, dentro de `address`, recoges el `cp` con los segundos corchetes (`[]`).

Para sacar `lat`, por ejemplo, tendrías que meterte en un tercer diccionario con lo siguiente:

```py
lat = user['address']['geo']['lat']
print(lat)
```

Por cierto, la parte en la que sacas el nombre esta mal, si te fijas en el JSON que recibes, no existe nigun key llamado `nombre`, es `name`, por lo que esto te dara error:

```py
nombre = user['nombre']
print(nombre)
```

Para que funcione tienes que pasarlo a lo siguiente:

```py
nombre = user['name']
print(nombre)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!